# Unable to use maxAllowedContentLength and maxQueryString together in iis 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8

I tried using below tag in my web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
<requestFiltering>
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="15728640" maxUrl="4096" maxQueryString="32768" />
</requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
```

In this case maxAllowedContentLength works but the maxQueryString doesnt work even though it is set max.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add the following to httpRuntime. According to MSDN, the correct element to modify to reset maxQueryStringLength in web.config is the `<httpRuntime>` element inside the `<system.web>` element, see [httpRuntime Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/e1f13641(v=vs.100)) (ASP.NET Settings Schema). Try modifying that element see below.

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="15728640" maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="4096"/>
</system.web>
```

Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/e1f13641(v=vs.100)) to httpRuntime variables